# Installing CImg on ubuntu from bash script

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, default, software-uninstall

I would like to install CImg from a non-interactive bash script

I've tried doing this using

```
apt install -y cimg-dev
```

Which works until the installer get to asking me about what region I am in

This is fine if for an interactive install, but I want this to be in a bash script so I don't have to manually set the region each time.

What's a suitable way to do this?

I'm not sure if it is possible to queue up the region selection options somehow, or if there is a way to set them before he command starts.

Comment: I think it might be related to dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/84521/automate-dpkg-reconfigure-tzdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331836/apt-get-install-tzdata-noninteractive), it turned out I needed to figure out how to install the timezone (tzdata) program non-interactively, rather than cimg.

For those interested my script is

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade -y

apt-get install -y libx11-dev 

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Australia/Brisbane /etc/localtime
apt-get install -y tzdata
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

apt-get install -y cimg-dev
```